# Trim +1 out of phone number node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a string containing a phone number in this format:
+12345678912

I want to trim the +1 out of the string so that it's like this:
2345678912

How would I do this regular expression in node.js

Answer (score 6):

Since country codes are different (they aren't all `+1`), I would say that the best way to do this is to trim out the expression where there is a plus sign followed by a number.

This should do it:

```
.replace(/^\+[0-9]/, '');
```

Testing:

```
"+12345".replace(/^\+[0-9]/, '');   // 2345
"+2345".replace(/^\+[0-9]/, '');    // 345
```

Of course if you only wanted to use the `+1`, just swap out the `[0-9]` with a `1`.

Comment: One amendment: Use `^` at the beginning to make sure the match happens at the start.

Comment: Most [country calling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) look to actually be longer than one digit, so this could malform any non-North American/US phone number.

Comment: @RyanKinal Good call, added the ^

Comment: @ajp15243 - Good point, I didn't know about the multi-digit codes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regular expression to simply remove a `+1` from the beginning of a string; it is overkill.  In this case, it is fine to say:

```
if (phoneNumber && phoneNumber.indexOf('+1') === 0) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(2);
}
```

However, the *general* solution to the problem of stripping country codes would have to consider all known country codes, which exist in several places, including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes).  It will need a few lines of code, though.  You have to take into account things like:

- If your string starts with `+1` then the country code is 1.
- If your string starts with a `+2`, then if the next character is `0` or `7`, you have a two-digit country code, otherwise if the second character is an `8` then you have an error, otherwise you have a 3-digit code.

There are similar rules for the first digit after the `+` being a 3 through 9.

At this point, a regex becomes an interesting, although wild-looking solution, it has the following form

```
^\+[1|2[07]|2[1-69]\d|  ..the rest of it goes here...  ]
```

A related SO question: [Regular Expression (RegEx) For Phone Numbers With Country Code Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777375/regular-expression-regex-for-phone-numbers-with-country-code-check)

**EDIT**

One of the things that makes the general problem difficult is that the list of country codes can expand.  Right now, there are no country codes starting with 28, but that group is reserved for future expansion, so your code would have to change if new codes are assigned.  And it's true that the full regex would be quite long, hard to read, and error prone.  Some kind of table-driven approach with a function would IMHO be the nicest way to go, but unless you are in the telecommunications business I'm thinking you can write an app which keeps the calling code distinct from the number. :)

Comment: If you *were* to do it with regex (which you shouldn't, I'm only writing this so you, OP, can learn a little regex) it'd be `.replace(/^\+1/, '')`. `^` means "the string must start here", `\+` is a literal `+` and `1` is a literal `1`.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I wanted

Comment: Excellently detailed answer. The complexity of country codes is not as simple as `+N`